# problems with mysql connector c++ on linux

Tags: c++, mysql-connector

say my ip adress is `127.0.0.1:8081` with user `root` and password `root`

and i want to connect to mysql via c++

this is working via browser and `127.0.0.1:8081/phpmyadmin/` where i can type in my password and user name and select a server, for instance i select server `C`

going by the example on the web page I am unable to connect to the server with the following error

```
driver = get_driver_instance();
  con = driver->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3306", "root", "root");
  /* Connect to the MySQL test database */
  con->setSchema("test");


# ERR: Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0 (MySQL error code: 2013, SQLState: HY000 )
success
```

What am i doing wrong? Am i supposed to specific the server as well?

**edit:**
the only information the website gives me is

```
 Server: C via TCP/IP
    Server version: 5.1.63-0ubuntu0.11.10.1
    Protocol version: 10
    User: root@website.com
    MySQL charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I read you right, you have an http server answering to point 3306, not mysql. You should find out what port your mysql is listening to. Perhaps, you can find it in `phpmyadmin` setup for server `C`.

But generally, this sounds like a weird setup and you're doing wrong more or less everything.

Comment: i'll re edit the example its up and running at port 8081 i just used the example ip adress from the web

Comment: how do i find out what port the sql server is listening too?

Comment: it should be 3036 its preety much the default ubuntu setup

Comment: Yes, it should be 3036. Can you connect to this port using `mysql` command line tool?

Comment: saying what? What did you do? `mysql -u root -p -h localhost` ?

Comment: `mysql --host="tcp://127.0.0.1:8081" --user=root --password=glassless`
and i tried with ports 22 , 8081 and 3036 as well as with and with out tcp:// , with my own ip adress

Comment: i found the ip adress of the server it was indeed different but now i get a different error  `Access denied for user 'root'@'192.168.1.104' (using password: YES) (MySQL error code: 1045, SQLState: 28000 )`

Comment: i fixed it i just had to add the user privleges !